# How to load swf file with event handlers in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling

```
stop();

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
nc.connect(null); 
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
var listener:Object = new Object(); 
listener.onMetaData = function(md:Object):void{}; 

listener.onPlayStatus = function(info : Object) : void {
    trace("onPlayStatus:" +info.code + " " + info.duration);
    if (info.code == "NetStream.Play.Complete") {
        var endLoader:Loader = new Loader();
  endLoader.load(new URLRequest("secondmovie.swf"));
  addChild(endLoader);
  initializeVideo();

    }
};
ns.client = listener; 

vid1.attachNetStream(ns); 


var movietoplay:String = "firstmovie.flv"; 
ns.play(movietoplay);

function initializeVideo():void {
 ns.close();     
}
```

Can anyone help me load the swf once the flv is done playing? I think I'm just not loading the swf right because the flv plays correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swf should already be loaded when the video complete event fires, this way it would start playing instantly as opposed to waiting for it to load , then play. simply preload the swf and when the video finishes , add the swf to the display list.

at the moment you wait for the video to complete to start loading , not playing the swf , meaning that there will be a delay proportional to the swf size , before it starts playing

```
stop();

//start the swf loading process
var endLoader:Loader = new Loader();
endLoader.load(new URLRequest("secondmovie.swf"));

//start the video
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
nc.connect(null); 
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
var listener:Object = new Object(); 

listener.onMetaData = function(md:Object):void{}; 
listener.onPlayStatus = function(info : Object) : void {
    trace("onPlayStatus:" +info.code + " " + info.duration);

    if (info.code == "NetStream.Play.Complete") 
    {
        //unless the swf size is really big or the video really short , 
        //the swf should be loaded
        //add it it should start playing straight away.
        addChild(endLoader);
        initializeVideo();
    }
};
ns.client = listener; 

vid1.attachNetStream(ns); 


var movietoplay:String = "firstmovie.flv"; 
ns.play(movietoplay);

function initializeVideo():void {
 ns.close();     
}
```

Comment: thats what I thought it may be doing. What I want to happen is after a FLV is done playing, a SWF opens...all I have to open a swf after FLV is a timer, and that doesnt work sometimes. Someone here gave me the code for the listener, to listen when it gets done dynamically, then open a SWF..??

Comment: @mike: If PatrickS has solved your problem correctly please consider marking his response as answer. You can do that by clicking on the tick mark to the left of his post.

Comment: I can't get onPlayStatus to work, it just never fires. I can get duration from onMetaData, but onPlayStatus which is declared in the same object stays silent through the video play. Does it actually work for you?